# Can't apply isolation

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to implement transaction with psycopg.

This is the SQL I want to implement:

```
BEGIN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SELECT * FROM students WHERE matnr = 123457 FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE studierende
SET name = 'Name' WHERE matnr = 123457;
COMMIT;
```

But when I connect

```
    self.dbConnect = pg.connect(host=db_host, 
database=db_database, user=db_user, password=db_password)
```

and set the isolation level

```
self.dbConnect.set_isolation_level(3);
```

and execute the SQL with `.execute("SELECT...FOR UPDATE", data)`

The row should be locked for others to select.
But although I set the isolation level, I can still execute and even update the row from an other, parallel, query (It should stay under lock until the first user commits his changes).

In the psql terminal this isn't possible. But here it is. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you do it, it might have something to do with Autocommit.  With autocommit on, you issue a SELECT FOR UPDATE and it COMMITs right away and releases the lock so you have to do BEGIN then your SELECT FOR UPDATE, then hold off before COMMIT while you test it in another session.